# Avoiding typing name twice when creating namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

`namedtuple` creation often requires typing its name twice, once to provide the name of the module level variable containing the new class, and once to set the `__name__` attribute of the new class (used for printing out the class objects, I think mostly for debugging, logging, etc.).

Is there any downside, besides being slightly unexpected, to using a function (`new_namedtuple` below) to reduce boilerplate code? And is using `globals()` correct or should it use `exec`? Of course, it would only work when we want the class name and the variable name to be the same:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> def new_namedtuple(name, *args, **kwargs):
...   globals()[name] = namedtuple(name, *args, **kwargs)
...
>>> new_namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
>>> p = Point(x=1, y=10)
>>> p
Point(x=1, y=10)
```

Edit: @Moinuddin Quadri pointed out imports will fail. That's no good. So let me rephrase my question: what's the best way to do it? Or is it not worth it?

Comment: Mutating the global namespace can lead to gotchas and fun debugging... What if I had a class named `Point` in scope - this would clobber it - and isolating the scope as to why that suddenly stopped working would be interesting as your `new_namedtuple` may not even be run sometimes meaning that run-time behaviour is going to go funky.

Comment: @JonClements agreed. Although strictly speaking the same can be said about `Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')`: this line of code may be run only sometimes, and thus occasionally but not always clobber the previously defined `class Point` (that accidentally had the same name).

Comment: I don't like it.  A better way to avoid the duplication would be with metaclasses.

Comment: @max of course - but that's more explicit and obvious an issue and more easily searched than a "sneaky" function side-effect...

Comment: @max: What is your definition of major downside? As I see lack of import as major downside. Do you mean downside at the object level of the `namedtuple`?

Comment: @wim how would you do it with metaclasses? metaclass can't know the name of the variable the class is saved in, so wouldn't it still have to do the same work as `new_namedtuple`?

Comment: @max The other thing to bear in mind is that `namedtuple` works by building up code and then executing it... so by not storing a reference to it - your function will be re-doing that each time... which is going to be far from efficient

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri sorry, I wasn't clear. That would be a major one :)

Comment: @JonClements well, I would use `new_namedtuple('Point', 'x y')` only in those places where I would have otherwise used `Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')`. So the cost of class creation would be paid the same number of times (usually once per program assuming the class is imported properly by other modules who need it, and assuming `new_namedtuple` is fixed to allow imports).

Comment: @max anyway... my main point is that if you use `Point = ...` (let's say inside a function) what'll happen is that you'll just shadow an existing `Point` class... When you mutate the globals - you're clobbering/overwriting it - to get it back you need to re-define it as it was originally...

Comment: @max  You subclass the generated class, not bind it to a name directly.  I will add an example answer.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this, just to save few key strokes? If yes, `new_namedtuple('Point', 'x y')` and `Point=namedtuple('Point', 'x', 'y')`, there is difference of just 2 key-strokes, but later is much more readable and you need not to worry about any harm, and post it on SO to know about it if there is any :)

Comment: @JonClements oh I didn't even think about it.. I somehow assumed all namedtuples would be defined at the global scope. Of course, that's also not good. I'm leaning towards "it's not worth it" as the correct answer.

Comment: This can't be sanely done with Python as is, but there are proposals for similar behavior https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-ideas/GWHOwdhMVGE%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 5):

The recommend way of using typing.NamedTuple in 3.6 will satisfy your request but requires you use type hinting.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int

p = Point(1, 10)
```

Typing hinting rubs some the wrong way. Unfortunately, collections.namedtuple doesn't support this useage, fingers crossed that changes.

Comment: Wow how did this get through into python 3.6? I thought a similar approach of defining attributes without assignment for `Enum` was rejected at the last minute because it looks weird and would confuse static analyzers. But I guess since it's in the language already, might as well use it.

Comment: And yeah, I definitely wouldn't do it unless I already planned to use type hinting; the "cost" of type hinting is way high for just a syntax convenience.

Comment: From the python docs:
The typing module has been included in the standard library on a provisional basis. New features might be added and API may change even between minor releases if deemed necessary by the core developers.

Comment: @max It went into typing outside traditional Python core development and got ported in, so there wasn't much discussion about it.  That said, the traditional function call approach becomes awkward once you try to add types and default arguments and this is a reasonable solution.   The ``Enum`` issue didn't apply because we also have a type declaration ``x: int`` which is now used in many contexts.  Linters can cope with those better than a bare variable ``x`` which appears more like a uninitialized variable lookup than a declaration.  In other words, I think this was a reasonable addition.

Comment: One other thought is that regular collections.namedtuple() wouldn't benefit nearly as much.  Not having to type the class name twice is a very minor savings in code and not worth the added complexity of a metaclass or worth the loss of the assignment being explicit.  In short, I think the OP is throwing too much firepower at too small of a problem.  Saving a few characters per module is rarely worth invoking hidden implicit assignment behaviors.  That is in part why the PEP 359 "make" statement was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see few downsides here. The biggest is that you cannot import `Point()` in other files.

Another is the readability for the other developers looking at the code. It is better to go with the default syntax (might be opinion based, but I consider it as downside).

Comment: Can it be fixed by adding the new name to the module inside `new_namedtuple()`?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest downside I can see is clarity.

If I see this line:

```
new_namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

I would be surprised to find out that `Point` is now a variable.

If there were a special syntax for this it might be clear, but there isn't.  This variable is being made in a very implicit manner.

[Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: I agree with your sentiments.  This is in part why the PEP 359 "make" statement was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest downside will be confusion for your end users (and maybe *you* down the line, it happens). People don't usually expect a function to mutate the global scope like this.

Functionally this doesn't have issues; you can modify `globals()` as you wish and it'll run just fine. Semantic arguments can be made against it; it really doesn't justify not typing a name twice.